# Add values of an array that has parent value in the key - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Well basically I have this array `$data`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 0
            [title] => produit 1
            [path] => produit-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 0
            [title] => Produit 2
            [path] => produit-2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent] => 0
            [title] => Produit 3
            [path] => produit-3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent] => 0
            [title] => Produit 4
            [path] => produit-4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent] => 2
            [title] => Sous produit 10
            [path] => sous-produit-10

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [parent] => 2
            [title] => Sous produit 11
            [path] => sous-produit-11
        )

)
```

And I'd like to check if the `data[$key]['parent']` exists in `['id']` and if so it concatenate the `title` of the array with its parent like this :

```
Array
    (
        [produit 1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Sous produit 11
                [1] => Sous produit 10
            )

        [Produit 2] => Produit 2
        [Produit 3] => Produit 3
        [Produit 4] => Produit 4
    )
```

Here's what I've tried and didn't work :

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $rslt[$value['id']]= $value;    
    }

$output = array();
foreach ($rslt as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($value['parent'],$rslt)){
        $new_key = $rslt[$value['parent']]['title'];
        $output[$new_key][] = $value['title'];
    }
    else $output[$value['title']] = $value['title'];
}
```

Any way I can do this? Much appeciated.

Comment: So you want to group the items with the `parent` id that is the same?

Comment: Yes @Darren that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get parent by title but you save parent id as key

```
// create id => data array
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $rslt[$value['id']] = $value;
}

$output = array();
// create id => labels array
foreach($rslt as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($value['parent'], $rslt)) {
        // append title to parent
        $output[$value['parent']][] = $value['title'];
    } else {
        // forgot to add parents 
        $output[$value['id']] = array($value['title']);
    }
}

$final = array();
// create parent label => labels array
foreach($output as $key => $value) {
    $final[$value[0]] = $value; // parent will always be first array item
}
```

Comment: Sorry @insanebits but that doesn't output the array I need.

Comment: @user3350731 there was bug in my logic, give it a try, notice that `$final` will hold your expected values

Comment: Still it renders the array not like the requested output since it added the $key of the one which has childs in itself http://codepad.org/A6EeIUlu

Comment: I said that `$final` holds the array and not the `$output` http://codepad.org/phtOkbR4